# Laravel Media library pro - Unchanged value of custom properties not persisting

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-medialibrary

Using custom properties with media library pro collection in Livewire, only changed values save. Existing, unchanged custom property values are deleted.

- If I change both properties, they save.
- If I change neither
  property, they remain saved.
- If I change one of the custom properties
  and not the other, changed one is saved, the other deleted.

I'd expect the unchanged to remain unless specifically cleared. How can I do that?

Code to hydrate:

```
$this->invoices = $this->model->getMedia('job_invoices');
```

Code to save:

```
$this->model
    ->syncFromMediaLibraryRequest($this->invoices)
    ->withCustomProperties('invoice_value', 'invoice_date')
    ->toMediaCollection('job_invoices');

$this->clearMedia('job_invoices');
```

Custom property blade template:

```
<div class="media-library-field">
    <label class="media-library-label">Value</label>
    <input
        class="media-library-input"
        type="text"
        {{ $mediaItem->livewireCustomPropertyAttributes('invoice_value') }}
    />
    @error($mediaItem->customPropertyErrorName('invoice_value'))
        <span class="media-library-text-error">
            {{ $message }}
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>

<div class="media-library-field">
    <label class="media-library-label">Date</label>
    <input
        class="media-library-input"
        type="date"
        {{ $mediaItem->livewireCustomPropertyAttributes('invoice_date') }}
        x-on:change.debounce="$wire.setCustomProperty('{{ $mediaItem->uuid }}', 'invoice_date', document.getElementsByName('{{ $mediaItem->customPropertyAttributeName('invoice_date') }}')[0].value)"
    />
    @error($mediaItem->customPropertyErrorName('invoice_date'))
        <span class="media-library-text-error">
            {{ $message }}
        </span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Example of data sent when changing one field and not the other:

```
  "e944d21f-1cf6-4139-b3c1-f7cd9cb114b0" => array:10 [▼
    "name" => "INV-0297"
    "fileName" => "Invoice-INV-0297.pdf"
    "uuid" => "e944d21f-1cf6-4139-b3c1-f7cd9cb114b0"
    "previewUrl" => ""
    "order" => 1
    "customProperties" => array:2 [▼
      "invoice_date" => "2023-01-01"
      "invoice_value" => "123"
    ]
    "extension" => "pdf"
    "size" => 75910
    "createdAt" => 1683887419
    "custom_properties" => array:1 [▼
      "invoice_value" => "1,234"
    ]
  ]
```

In the above example only the `invoice_value` changed. The original values can be seen in `customProperties`.

As an aside, this also effects validation. A field **with a value**, when saved with no changes will raise a validation error.